# How to assign user to navigation pane in Microsoft Navision with SQL?

Tags: sql-server, navision

I would like to be able to give a user permissions for Microsoft Nav via SQL scripts and reached the point when I need to assign a user to menu's on Navigation Pane. is it possible to do in SQL? Cannot find the corresponding table in Database.

Answer (score 0):

You need either User Personalization or User Profile